# Is Kurama-dera popular with those praying for love?

Tags: japan, temples, shinto

A Japanese friend said that Kurama-dera temple in Kyoto, Japan is popular with those praying for love, both with people who are single and those who are in an existing relationship.

However, I can't find a mention of that on either the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurama-dera) or [Japanese-language](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9E%8D%E9%A6%AC%E5%AF%BA) editions of Wikipedia, or Japanese Wikipedia's article on [Yuki-jinja shrine](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%B1%E5%B2%90%E7%A5%9E%E7%A4%BE), or by googling about Kurama-dera and love. However, the English edition of Wikipedia mentions that the temple isn't well-known by non-Japanese, so that may explain the lack of google hits confirming this.

Is Kuruma-dera popular with those praying for love?

Comment: Fortunately there are still lots of places that haven't been totally revealed on the internet, that locals love and tourists haven't over run.

Comment: @Tom don't worry - with the tiny amount of web traffic Travel.SE gets, tourists still won't overrun it. Besides, there's plenty of places that get mentioned by Lonely Planet that aren't overrun by tourists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: @mts - FWIW it's difficult to see how this question is not about travel?

Comment: @mts visiting temples and shrines is a activity a lot of visitors to Kyoto do. I'm wanting to make sure I visit the correct one.

Comment: If you want to go to one in Kyoto well known for praying for love, the 地主神社　within the 清水寺 complex would be a better (and more accessible) bet. After conferring with some colleagues who live in Kyoto, they seem to just suggest that 鞍馬寺 is generally a spiritual place rather than one related specifically to love. My experiences from the three times I have been there seemed to confirm this. Some online searches (in Japanese) mention it as a "romantic power spot" but otherwise I couldn't find anything that would relate it to love.